# Multiple namespaces routes and forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, namespaces, form-for

I'm running a Rails 3 application.
My directories are looking like that:

```
-app 
  -controllers
    -group
      -groups_controller
      -admin
        -groups_controller
```

And my routes file:

```
#routes.rb

namespace :group do
  resources :groups
  namespace :admin do
    resources :groups
  end
end
```

The problem is in the form, who is common **to new and edit**.
The following code doesn't work, so how should I do in my forms or in my routes ?

```
#_forms.html.erb

<%= form_for [:group, :admin, @group] do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Is your controller called `Group::GroupsController`?

Comment: one is Group::GroupsController and the other one Group::Admin::GroupsController

Comment: So why have this `Group::` namespace wrapping the classes?

Comment: I need it for my organisation. Next to that I have an other namespace admin (app/controllers/admin) !